# Assigning a named Range value to a variable (Excel VBA) - Novice

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have about 10 days of VBA Excel experience so please excuse my mistakes/ignorance.  Also I likely can't find the solution as I don't know the language, thus my questions are not meaningful/on the mark.  my queries return mostly "how to name a range using VBA in Excel".

I am building a workbook that contains test results for control parts that company I work for  manufactures.  There are 28 parts with 6 performance criteria each.

I am trying to "grab" a value for each part and parameter to be used in conditional formatting formula: '=rnSource +/- (rnSource*Tolerance)'.

Each part number has a SN and 6 test point results (TPs).  I named the ranges (single cells) as SN_TPx (x, being 1, 2, 3,...6).  These named cells are in a different worksheet than conditional formatting target worksheets (28 of these, 1/SN).  Individual worksheet contain current run test results(sheets are named using a SN).  Below code worked fine when I used `SN_TPx` in place of `rnSource`.

Reason:  I can reuse the code with modification of one "Dim" rather than copy/past code 168 times and changing cell references throughout the code (8 occurrences).  I also have 7 other product lines that I will need to apply this to.

In my code I attempted to:  `Dim rnSource As Range`, then assign `SN_TPx` `to rnSource` using `Set rnSource = SN_TPx`.  This results in: "Run-time error '424': Object required"

In last 12 hours I have attempted to find a solution on line with no avail.

I have tried using `rnSource =` :
`SN_TPx.Value`  - '424' error

`Range(SN_TPx).Value` - Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

`Range("SN_TPx").Value` - Code runs but...my Conditional Formatting formula results in: "Cell Value < rnSource-(rnSource*Tolerance)" which doesn't seem to return value of SN_TPx rather "rnSource" text (formatted value font is not affected)

`Worksheet("Sheet3").Range(SN_TPx)` - Compile error:  Sub or Function not defined (Worksheet)

`Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("SN_TPx")` - Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

I have tried other pieces of code that I don't recall anymore but I am sure there is a simple solution, if one is familiar with VBA, that I am missing.

Code below:

```
Sub TP1_CondFormat_AV()
'***   Attempt to handle ranges (source and target) of CondFormat by setting dims and ranges upfront_
' then execute CondFormat routine for each set of dims and ranges


With ActiveSheet

'** par - define needed variables
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim TP1_Range As Range
Dim TP2_Range As Range

'Dim rnSource As Variant ' fail
'Dim rnSource As Integer ' fail
Dim rnSource As Range
Dim rnTarget As Range
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

'*** par - create a range called "rnTarget" which consists of r1 and r2 ranges
Set r1 = Range("L2:L4")
Set r2 = Range("L7:L1048576")
Set rnTarget = Union(r1, r2)
rnTarget.Name = "TP1"    'Name the rnTarget as "TP1"

Set rnSource = Range(SN_TP1).Value  '== troubleshooting, unable to point rnSource to "SN_TP1" value

End With

rnTarget.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:="=rnSource-(rnSource*Tolerance)"
rnTarget.FormatConditions(rnTarget.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With rnTarget.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Color = -4165632
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    rnTarget.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    rnTarget.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:="=rnSource+(rnSource*Tolerance)"
    rnTarget.FormatConditions(rnTarget.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With rnTarget.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    rnTarget.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    End Sub
```

Thank you for taking your valuable time in helping me out,

Pawel

Comment: In addition to @urdearboy comment, explicitly assign `Range` to a specific sheet. And don't use `ActiveSheet`. Use `With Worksheets("mySheet") | Set rn Source = .Range("SN_TP1")`, for example (pipe is line separator).

Comment: I'd recommend not setting `r2` to cover every row. Are you really working on every single row on your sheet? Bets practice is to limit your code to the scope of your actual range.

Comment: the r1 and r2 with the Union is to account for a some headers in the Sheet (which I don't want to format).  Reason for r2 covering every row is to allow for new data that will be added over the years to come.  I don't know how to do dynamic range yet

Comment: thank you for your lightning quick replies.  I do appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to create a VBA Range variable for a Excel named range you just have to add quotes. Note that you should remove the `.Value` you currently have as that is a property of a range (*example of how to access the value of your variable is below*)

---

```
Set rnSource = Range("SN_TP1")
'Debug.Print rnSource.Value
```

Comment: This method almost worked for me.  The conditional formatting ends up with a formula that looks like "Cell Value < rnSource - (rnSource*Tolerance)"  but font is not formatted.  How can I add a screenshot?

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue which is not the intent of this question. If you can reference the cell now, then your question is answered

Comment: Fair enough but I was attempting to replace SN_TPx with a single refernce that I can adjust to each TP and SN by changing it while defining it (Dim rnSource As Range than change 101_TP1 in Set rnSource) otherwise I have to change 8 times per SN  per TP.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to loop or something? You may need to revise your question because that’s not clear

Comment: in short, yes. I just have practically no experience so looping seems out of reach still.  learning as I go.  What got works but to apply it fully takes a lot of find/replace, not robust or scalable.  You are also correct that my question is likely not clear...I am having a hard time to express what I need.

Comment: Again, I do appreciate your comments and wisdom

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input @urdearboy and @Scott Holtzman.  Your answers were correct and helped me figure out why my proposed method will not work.

When I `Set rnSource = .Range("SN_TPx")` it does assign `SN_TPx` value to `rnSource` (`Debug.Print` confirms it) but...worksheet does not recognize `rnSource` name.  Thus, the Conditional Format formula will not work since it contains `Cell < =rnSource-(rnSource*Tolerance)`

```
[CondFormatFail.jpg][1]
```

This means that despite changing `rnSource` value by changing `SN_TPx`, in the end my whole workbook would end up with the same `rnSource value`...last one assigned to it.

For now I will have to hard code `SN_TPx` into my conditional formatting and apply to appropriate ranges.  With time I will streamline it and make it more efficient.

Thank you again!